# Install .net remoting objects on IIS 7.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, remoting

I found myself in situation when I have to host .NET Remoting objects in IIS 7.5.
First I tried to follow standard way for previous version of IIS: I created dll with my class, put it in
bin folder, created web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.runtime.remoting>
    <application>
      <service>
        <wellknown
           mode="SingleCall" objectUri="FunctionOne.rem"
           type="remoting, remoting"/>
      </service>
      <channels>
        <channel ref="http"/>
      </channels>
   </application>
  </system.runtime.remoting>
</configuration>
```

But any attempts to check it through Internet Explorer address bar returned 404 Error for me. I tried to
find solution in google but as .NET remoting is pretty old technology it seemed alsmost no one needs to host  it new versions of IIS. Are there any sources of information I could use? Thank you

Answer (score -1):

.NET Remoting is not pretty old technology - you are obviously someone who never read the documentation.

Why do you think you can access a remoting object via HTTP in a browser? Remoting doe snot use HTML and is not a web service metadata readable technology.